# How to test an action creator with a fetch API request

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs, create-react-app

I have a create-react-app with Redux and Jest for testing. I am using fetch to make the API request from an action creator. As I am writing tests I found that for what ever reason – anyway I am trying to mock this request - it is still trying to make the actual request to the API and getting a Network Connection Error (so I get the catch from the request each time when test). It might be worth mentioning that this works fine in the browser.

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { SUBMIT_SUCCESS, EMPLOYEE_DETAILS, ERROR } from './actionTypes';
import { API_URL } from '../../Constants';

 export function getEmployeeDetails(id) {
   return async dispatch => {
    try {
      let payload = await (await fetch(`${API_URL}/users/${id}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { jwt: localStorage.getItem('jwt') },
      })).json();

      dispatch(getEmployeeDetailsSuccess(payload.user));
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch(errorCatch(err));
    }
  };
}
```

I have tried this - https://medium.com/@ferrannp/unit-testing-with-jest-redux-async-actions-fetch-9054ca28cdcd

I have also tired this - https://medium.com/@kellyrmilligan/testing-async-actions-in-redux-with-isomorphic-fetch-and-fetch-mock-35f98c6c2ee7

And basically spent a couple of days trying to work on this.

What am I doing wrong? Any chance to get a working example of how to test this action?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to test exactly? For mocking `fetch`, there are things like [fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock) but maybe you could also just refactor your code so that it doesn't depend directly on `fetch` works.

For example, to just check that the right actions get dispatched, you could use something along these lines:

```
export function getEmployeeDetails(fetcher, id) {
  return async dispatch => {
    let payload = await fetcher(id);

    if (/* payload is good */) {
      dispatch(getEmployeeDetailsSuccess(payload.user));
    }
    else {
      dispatch(errorCatch(err))
    }
  };
}
```

Now you can test your method by passing in a function that returns a good/bad  payload, and [make sure that the right actions are dispatched](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html). In the normal code, you can use `fetch` as you were, but passing a function that handles that logic, rather than including it directly in the action creator.